# How to show full legend without the scrollbar in plotly in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, png

**How do I get rid of the scrollbar to show the full legend and save the plot as a png?**

I am trying to save a plotly graph in r, but the legend has a scroll bar.

**My code:**

```
  plot_ly(data = stats_salary, x = ~Salary, y = ~PPG, color = ~Team,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = ~paste("Player: ", Player,
                      "<br>Salary: ", "$",format(Salary, big.mark = ","),
                      "<br>PPG: ", round(PPG, digits = 3),
                      "<br>Team: ", Team)) %>% 
  layout(
    title = "Salary vs Point Per Game by Player",
    xaxis = list(title = "Player's Salary"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Points per Game")
  )
```

**My output:**

[Plotly Graph Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACl8N.png)

I would like to save this chart as a png. Whenever I run this code, I get a NULL error:

```
export(plot, file = "plot.png")
```

How do I get rid of the scrollbar to show the full legend and save the plot as a png?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height manually so the legend fits:

```
layout(height = 600)
```

I haven't found a way to automatically size the figure so the legend doesn't scroll.